# virt-manager - first run, error: Unable to connect to libvirt

Tags: virt-manager

virt-manager 1:1.5.1 On Ubuntu.

Menu/File/Add Connection/Connect

Error Dialog:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt qemu:///system
```

libvirtd.service status shows it is running and that there are no errors

Journal contains following

```
28153: error : virGetGroupID:1123 : invalid argument: Failed to parse group 'tss'
28153: error : virGetUserID:1043 : invalid argument: Failed to parse user 'tss'
```

'tss' does not exist as user in /etc/shadow or group in /etc/group

I could simply add tss as user and group. Will that be enough or is this indicative of something I've done wrong? Though I don't know what that could have been because all I've done is install.

I have been happily using VirtualBox for years but VB now requires VT-X which the old target machine does not support. I've tried installing an old VBox but get so many errors (even after --fix-broken) that I don't want to mess with it. So I'm giving virt-manager a try.

UPDATE: 
I added user tss without any special privilege and the machine now starts. However It does not get far, runs very slowly, because of the lack of CPU  virtualization. So... I will not be using this machine for VM.

Comment: Think VB needs VT-X only if emulating 64bit machines.  If you are only emulating 32bit vms, then VB should still work.

Comment: @ivanivan  I've tried several 32-bit Ubuntu ISOs and get the Guru Meditation error. However I just tried a 32-bit Debian 9 and it works fine. I will post this over on the Ubuntu group.

Comment: This turns out to be a kernel issue. I managed to create an old Ubuntu server 17.10 but after one kernel upgrade it was broken.